# Why does if-not call "not", rather than just inverting arguments?

Tags: clojure

I'm studying the source of clojure.core.

```
(defmacro if-not
  ([test then] `(if-not ~test ~then nil))
  ([test then else]
  `(if (not ~test) ~then ~else)))
```

As to the second form, why not just

`` ([test then else] `(if ~test ~else ~then) ``

Comment: As an aside, editing a question in a way that invalidates existing answers tends to be frowned on here, with asking a new, separate question (and, if the original question isn't likely to be useful to anyone else, perhaps politely asking the person owning the answer to delete it, if that answer is upvoted and thus preventing question deletion) as the general Right Thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, sorry. New to the community, unfamiliar with the conventions. May I ask how should I proceed properly?

Comment: (see ie. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254521/editing-question-for-new-answer for discussion on meta around conventions for question edits impacting existing answers -- that said, this isn't by any means an egregious case; what the rules are *really* out to avoid is "chameleon questions", as described in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: Probably wait the owner of the existing answer to get back with their take -- if they're OK with editing or deleting their answer, then everything's fine. Since the original answerer's interpretation of the question isn't as something that strikes me as particularly likely to help others, and the intended question is reachable (just not the *only* interpretation reachable) from the original text, this isn't a particularly bad case, which is why this is just a gentle nudge for future reference instead of a rollback. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Appreciate your guidance. I guess I should've pondered over the question a bit more when I first raised it :)

Comment: I completely misunderstood the question. I deleted my answer

Comment: I just see readibility/maintenance explanation since performance is better with your version (little in absolute value even for big data like 1 billion iterations) and logic is theoritically coherent

Comment: My original guess was that it reads better than the proposed version. It describes the code it expands to more closely, which may be considered valuable for maintainability and when debugging.

Comment: Rich added it and I doubt anyone has questioned it. It is pretty minor https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/c5e8c6f06292fab26d29cb951d8400394e0f8258

Comment: Yours is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks just a style of coding.

```
(if-not test then else)

(if (not test) then else)

(if test else then)
```

The above code will work the same way. There are multiple way to write code to do the same thing.

The author of `if-not` macro might have thought that it would be better to write the code that way.

```
(defmacro if-not
  ...
  ([test then else]
    `(if (not ~test) ~then ~else)))
```

When we read this code (above), we can think in the order of `if`, `then`, `else`, quite straightforward.

```
(defmacro if-not
  ...    
  ([test then else]
    `(if ~test ~else ~then)
```

Yes, this will work fine. However, in terms of readability, the order `then` and `else` are swapped, and it might cause confusing.

That's why (in my guess) the author implemented `if-not` in that way.

Comment: I guess I should've put this into the question when I posted it. I'm trying to implement all the functions in clojure.core myself as a way to learn Clojure. When I compared my ver. with the Clojure ver., I was kinda surprised (I thought performance comes first at this level of coding). I think the ver. below is pretty obvious (the first thing that popped into my head when I thought about `if-not`), the author must have thought about it and decided not to use it. I'm trying to understand what I was missing.